# how to preventoverlapping between two qdockwidgets in same area?

Tags: qt, qdockwidget, tabbing

I have two qDockWidgets have the same allowed area ,qt by default allows overlapping between two dock widgets so the two dock widgets will be a one tab widget . I want to stop this behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to stop the tabbing between two dock widget add this line of code in your application

```
setDockOptions(QMainWindow::AnimatedDocks);
```

the default value of DockOptions in qt is `AnimatedDocks | AllowTabbedDocks`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to setFocusPolicy to Qt::ClickFocus, which mean the QWidget will accept focus only by mouse click and not by keyboard tab.

more info at this link http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop

Comment: I am sorry I think my question was not clear enough. I did not mean  keyboard tab key when I said tabbing I meant overlapping between two dock widgets so the two dock widget will be a one tab widget .. what I need is to stop this behavior